# Make Array.filter() return items which are false instead of true

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I will use the example from the MDN [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) docs.

we can pass decoupled functions into higher order functions like this:

```
function isBigEnough(value) {
  return value >= 10;
}

var filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(isBigEnough);
// filtered is [12, 130, 44]
```

Using the example above as reference, is it possible to filter results which are not 'big enough' without defining another decoupled function `isSmallEnough()`? In order words, We would like to return `[5, 8]`.

Can we reuse `isBigEnough` to achieve this?

Comment: In ES2015: `const negate = func => (...args) => !func(...args);`
`const isSmallEnough = negate(isBigEnough);`

Comment: @PaoloMoretti With that `negate`, `func` will get the wrong `this` value.

Comment: @4castle Yeah it will be `undefined`. But that's what `.filter` does by default, unless you explicitly set it with the second argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function which returns the inverted form of a function:

```js
function not(predicate) {
  return function() {
    return !predicate.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}

function isBigEnough(value) {
  return value >= 10;
}

var filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(not(isBigEnough));
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

Negate the predicate:

```js
function isBigEnough(value) {
  return value >= 10;
}

var filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(function(value) {
  return !isBigEnough(value);
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: This is essentially an anonymous form of an `isSmallEnough` function. It's just as coupled to `isBigEnough` as the function which the OP didn't want.

Comment: Those are the sentences that appear in the OP's question: 
without defining another **decoupled** function isSmallEnough()? and 
Can we reuse isBigEnough to achieve this? He wanted to reuse the isBigEnough  function, and have it coupled to the new method. You're method is definitely more functional, but my low tech solution fits the question as well.

Comment: I'm just trying to think of what would be worse than defining another decoupled function. That would be defining a coupled function. With this solution, every time you change `isBigEnough` you also have to change all of the other functions which were coupled to it.

Comment: Again. This is not a generic functional solution, just a simple "fits this case" solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a wrapper for a not function.

```js
function isBigEnough(value) {
    return value >= 10;
}

var not = fn => (...args) => !fn(...args),
    filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(not(isBigEnough));
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the existing answers are correct, here's a slightly different take:

```
let not = x => !x;
let greaterThan = R.curryN(2, (x, y) => y > x);
let greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10); // === isBigEnough
let notGreaterThan10 = R.pipe(greaterThan10, not);

let items = list.filter(notGreaterThan10);
```

Uses the [ramda.js](http://ramdajs.com/) library for composition and currying.

Answer (score 0):

- I see now this is just an ES6 variation of On Dron's answer. Pretty sure he's right in that this would satisfy the test question.

  > Can we reuse `isBigEnough` to achieve this?

Yes, by slightly modifying your code we can even use the same filter method to return just the *false values*.

```
function isBigEnough(value) {
  return value >= 10;
}

var filterFalse = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(x => !isBigEnough(x));
// filterFalse - [5, 8]
```